# Using FastICA in Matlab to separate a mixture of Gaussian and Poisson matrices

Tags: matlab, gaussian, poisson

I need to generate a matrix with a Gaussian distribution (with values spread mainly from -5 to 5), a Poisson matrix, mix them and give them as input to the [Matlab FastICA](http://research.ics.tkk.fi/ica/fastica/).

I am a newbie on Matlab, distributions and ICA, so a few pointers would really help. I have been trying really hard but don't know whether I'm on the right track.

In order to generate the Gaussian and Poisson matrices, I generated two arrays:

```
s2 = poissrnd(2, 1, 40000); %Poisson distribution with lambda 2
s1 = rand(size(s2)) * 10 - 5; %Gaussian distribution and values ranging from -5 to 5
```

I then use the [reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html) function to generate two 200x200 matrices. When using [image](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/image.html), I get the following images:

[image] [image]

My 1st question is this: Is this the correct way to generate Gaussian and Poisson matrices in Matlab? Or are there some built-in functions which actually generate the matrices, instead of having to generate and reshape arrays?

Now, the 2nd problem: using [FastICA](http://research.ics.tkk.fi/ica/fastica/).

Referring to a very good answer at: [ICA (Independent Component Analysis) fast-fixed point algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206301/ica-independent-component-analysis-fast-fixed-point-algorithm), it mentions that FastICA needs each signal in a row.

I am therefore generating my signal matrix by:

```
S(1,:) = s1; %row 1
S(2,:) = s2; %row 2
```

I then generate a mixing matrix, add some noise, and give the resultant matrix as input to the fastica() function.

My question is: is it possible to give 2D data directly to FastICA? What if you have an image with many mixed signals and want to give it to ICA so that it can find the Independent Components?

A link to a tutorial explaining how to use FastICA on different inputs would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance to anyone who reads this post and tries to help. And sorry for the lengthy question, I wanted to make sure that it is well understood!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you create you mixed signal? FastICA will try to estimate the matrix you used for mixing (the original components). As long as you have a sufficient number of measurements for your observations (signals) FastICA can unmix any number of mixed signals. See, in the answer you linked to, four signals are being mixed and decomposed.

The data you put into FastICA already is 2D (m x n), just shaped to another size (1 x mn).

Comment: I generate a random 2x2 matrix (A) and then use X = A * S to mix the signals. I then use the command ica = fastica(X) and get a 2 * 40000 matrix. If I understood correctly, each row of the ica matrix should correspond to one of the original matrices. Is this correct?

Comment: I think I've been mixing the signal wrong though. What I actually want is a 200x200 matrix which is a mixture of both the Gaussian and Poisson matrices. I created such a matrix using the command M = rand(200) * s1M + rand(200) * s2M; (where s1M and s2M are the original matrices). However when I use ica = fastica(M), I get back a 199 * 200 matrix, and don't know how I can get the original signals from it.

Comment: No. Your first approach was correct (the 2x2 matrix). M = rand(200) * s1M + rand(200) * s2M; is not the way to do it. You need to understand how ICA works. If you want to successfully unmix two signals you will need to provide at least two measurements. You artificially produce these measurements by calculating X = A * S. The result you get from ICA (2 * 40000) should be what you wanted (reshape the rows into 200 x 200). If you are only interested in the estimated A, use [A, ~] = FASTICA (X).

Comment: Oh ok now I get it! 'Cause we actually need two 'mixed' images, not one. Just one last question, is the way I'm producing the Gaussian and Poisson images correct? Generating an array and then reshaping it? Or is there some other way in Matlab?

Comment: Yes, you need two measurements of your image that you put reshaped as vectors into ICA.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, now I understand. Am I generating the Gaussian and Poisson matrices correctly?

Comment: About the distributions: I think for poisson you are doing it correctly. For gaussian, however, using rand is not correct as it assumes a uniform distribution (not normal). So you would need to consider mean and variance to produce gaussian noise (sqrt(variance) * rand() + mean in pseudo code)

Comment: I just saw you are using randn which draws from standard normal distribution. So you are correct, sorry.

Comment: Actually no, I'm not correct 'cause I'm using rand. What I know about Gaussian distributions is basically that a great majority of the values will be within 3 standard deviations for the mean. Now how do I calculate the variance if I want (most of) my values to be within the range [-5, 5]? I don't think sqrt(10) * rand() is what I want, 'cause when I tried it I got no -ve values, and the max value in the matrix was 3.1623.

Comment: Assume mean is 0. randn() * 5: 68% of values in [-5,5], randn() * 10:    95% in [-5,5], randn() * 15: 99,7% in [-5,5].

Comment: Actually no, I thought that'd work but it didn't. When I do randn() * 15, most values are outside the [-5, 5] range.

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry. 3 * sigma should be equal to 5. So 5/3 * randn() gives 99.7% in [-5,5].

Comment: Yes, that IS what I want!! Thank you so very very much for your help and patience. I've been finding it difficult to learn and find very descriptive examples, especially for using FastICA. Thanks again.