# What is the best way for separating independent parts from a signal?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, signal-processing

I have a signal from a shape. This shape contains some different parts & this received signal is summation of signals from these different parts. To elucidate, I have superposition. I don't know how many parts are there at my shape. What I can suppose is that these signals are independent.
I'm going to separate these signals & extract them from the received signal by an algorithm.
I know that one way is using ICA. Is it best way? Is there any other way I can do ? Is it a reasonable fact that signals from these parts are independent?

*** Here is an example about fastica that I can not understand:
[ICA (Independent Component Analysis) fast-fixed point algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206301/ica-independent-component-analysis-fast-fixed-point-algorithm/5210386#5210386)

We have 4 observations of one signal. So we have 4 receivers that receive one signal at different positions. But why the answer has 4 rows? why it doesn't have 1 row? Because it is observation of 1 signal. Does it means that we have 4 sensors & 4 sources? How can we understand number of different parts? 
These questions are because I'm new in ICA.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing a typical Signal Processing problem, or more specifically, a source separation problem. First you must determine whether your problem is over determined or underdetermined. This means that if you Observation is more than the number of independent components that makes up the mixture, it is overdetermined and vice-versa.

To me, it looks like your problem is overdetermined, which makes it much easier. You can imagine it as a system of equations, say you have 4 observations Y1,Y2,Y3 and Y4 (which are the 4 rows of data you are talking about, and ofc you need all 4 rows). And say you have 4 independent source in your mixture. You can represent this as:

```
 Y1(t) = A(t)+B(t)+C(t)+D(t) %// let us just assume that the first observation is the sum of 4 components
 Y2(t) = (a*A(t))+(b*B(t))+(c*C(t))+(d*D(t)) %// Your observation 2 will be different from your observation 1, because it is composed of different distributions of your variables.
```

and Y3 and Y4 should follow suit. To separate, you have several methods from PCA, ICA, to model based approach such as GMM/HMM/FHMM and Neural Network based methods ANN/DNN etc. The specific method you choose is somewhat dependent on how mixed your signals are, in other words, how sparse is your signal. For example, if your signals are completely frequency independent, then a simple filter would suffice.

You choose ICA which returns 4 rows representing the 4 components of your mixture (assuming that you used ICA correctly). You need to provide your ICA result for us to help you further.